# Delete or remove any empty fields from a line stored in a shell variable

Tags: sed, grep

Input:

```
|        |19.2&deg;E|    | |Astra 1L|    |11597.00|V|26|Astra 1L|DVB-S|QPSK|22000| |5/6|ASTRA 1|, 33.8 Mbps&nbsp;|NID:1|TID:1026|    |  |
```

output :

```
19.2&deg;E|Astra 1L|11597.00|V|26|Astra 1L|DVB-S|QPSK|22000|5/6|ASTRA 1|, 33.8 Mbps&nbsp;|NID:1|TID:1026
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this sed:

```
sed 's/|[[:blank:]]\{1,\}//g; s/^|//; s/|$//' file
19.2&deg;E|Astra 1L|11597.00|V|26|Astra 1L|DVB-S|QPSK|22000|5/6|ASTRA 1|, 33.8 Mbps&nbsp;|NID:1|TID:1026
```

It also works with non gnu sed like BSD sed.

Comment: Working correctly, the output is exactly what i'm expecting.

Comment: Not really, if you have key as `|   19.2&deg;E   |`, you will lost whitespace in output.  but if you don't care, that's fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try using sed and something like:

```
echo $line | sed -r 's/\|\s*\|//g'
```

Answer (score 0):

Through grep and sed,

```
..... | grep -oP '(?<=\|)[^|]*[^|\s][^|]*' | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/|/g'
```

Example:

```
$ echo '|        |19.2&deg;E|    | |Astra 1L|    |11597.00|V|26|Astra 1L|DVB-S|QPSK|22000| |5/6|ASTRA 1|, 33.8 Mbps&nbsp;|NID:1|TID:1026|    |  |' | grep -oP '(?<=\|)[^|]*[^|\s][^|]*' | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/|/g'
19.2&deg;E|Astra 1L|11597.00|V|26|Astra 1L|DVB-S|QPSK|22000|5/6|ASTRA 1|, 33.8 Mbps&nbsp;|NID:1|TID:1026
```

Answer (score 0):

by GNU sed

```
sed -r ':a s/\|\s*\|/|/g ;t a' infile

|19.2&deg;E|Astra 1L|11597.00|V|26|Astra 1L|DVB-S|QPSK|22000|5/6|ASTRA 1|, 33.8 Mbps&nbsp;|NID:1|TID:1026|
```

if you assign as variable, use this command

```
echo $line |sed -r ':a s/\|\s*\|/|/g ;t a'
```

Comment: the command Work also but the | is already there in the beginning of the output.

Comment: if you need, just refer the other answers with `s/^|//; s/|$//`, that's for removing head and trail `|`